# CORS intermittent issues .net core 6.0

Tags: asp.net-core, cors

I have a method that is failing on cors, all the other methods work fine.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/api/bid/report/1?filter=0' from origin 'https://localhost:44307' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

**Startup.cs**

[image]
[image]

**Method failing**

````
[HttpGet("report/{eventId}")]
       [Authorize(Policy = "Client")]
       public async Task<ActionResult<List<Bid>>> Report(ReportFilter filter, int eventId)
       {
           var userId = HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
           var user = _userRepository.GetUser(int.Parse(userId));
           var clientId = 0;
           var _event = _eventsRepository.GetEvent(eventId);
           var client = _clientRepository.GetClient(_event.ClientId);
           if (user.UserType == UserType.Client)
           {
               //get client id 
               if(client.LeadUser.Id == user.Id)
               {
                   clientId = client.Id;
               }
           }
           else if (user.UserType == UserType.Admin)
           {
               clientId = client.Id;   
           }
           else
           {
               return Unauthorized();
           }
           

           var bids = new List<Bid>();
           switch (filter)
           {
               case ReportFilter.MostBids:
                   //return Ok(_reportsRepository.MostBids(eventId,clientId));
                   
               case ReportFilter.HighestBids:
                   return _reportsRepository.GetHighestBids(eventId,clientId);
                   
               case ReportFilter.MostRecent:
                   return _reportsRepository.MostRecentBids(eventId,clientId);
                   
                   
           }
           return NotFound();
       }```
````

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: did you call this api with postman? is it works fine?
sometimes when your code has a problem and get 500 (Error) , The browser return this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/api/bid/report/1?filter=0' from origin 'https://localhost:44307' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

It seems that you are hosting your site on Azure App Service, we can also configure CORS policy to specify allowed origins on Azure portal like below, which might be able to help fix this issue.

[image]

Comment: I am seeing the same issue but this fix is not working for me.